# Menu Hamburguesa impide llenar inputs de formulario

Tags: javascript, html, css

tengo un menu hamburguesa para la version mobile de un sitio, con un position fixed y un z-index 1. Lo que me pasa es q cuando llego a la parte del formulario, no me deja llenar los campos porq el menu esta por encima. Hay alguna forma de corregir esto? Gracias!

```
                <input type="checkbox" />


                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>

                <ul id="menu">
                <li> <a href="#quienes_somos"> Quiénes somos</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#servicios"> Servicios</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#edificios"> Edificios</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#contacto"> Contacto</a> </li>
            </ul> 
            </div>
            </nav>
```

y aqui el html del form

```
  <div class="form_contacto">
                <h5>CONTACTO</h5>
                <div class="form_container">
                    <form class="form" action="contacto.php" method="post">
                        <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
                        <input maxlength="100" required="required" id="name" type="text" name="name">

                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input maxlength="100" required="required" id="email" type="email" name="email">

                        <label for="message">Mensaje:</label>
                        <textarea maxlength="100" required="required" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" />
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Sin un codigo fuente, no podemos ayudarte con tu problema, lo que puedo recomendarte es que elabores reglas de CSS para cada resolucion de dispositivo, usando @media only screen and (max-width: ) {} con lo cual evitas  que se solape el menu sobre el formulario en visualizacion movil

Comment: ahi agregue los css de ambos

Comment: La propiedad `z-index` depende totalmente de la estructura **HTML**, solamente con el **CSS** poco podemos ver. ¿Podrías subirnos el **HTML** para poder reproducir lo que te ocurre?

Comment: ahi subi el html de ambos